# Can tell me how to get this weight paint option in Blender 2.8 (screenshots inside)

Tags: bones

[image]

[image]

The guy in the video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YSj1kksmY3I&list=PLyDqgzz1CZ31H5SDLg1j6YCSUJqyMZtnb&index=7&t=6m40s - describes it as "masking mode by vertex" and it lets him edit the individual weight of specific parts of a model by selecting vertices and inputting a number for the weight.

Any ideas of how to get this in 2.8? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable *Vertex Selection Masking For Painting*, then you can only paint the selected vertices. Now maybe I miss something but it looks like, unlike 2.7,it doesn't display any vertex, selected or not, so maybe the best way is to *Show Wire* in the *Viewport Overlays* panel, it still won't show any vertex though...

So if I'm right, to do what you want to do, it may be easier to switch to *Edit* mode and to use the *Weight* value and *Assign* button under the *Vertex Groups* list?

[image]